# how to embed external html file into current html file but without iframe tag

Tags: jquery, html, web, dojo

I need to open External website inside my current html file without iFrame

Help me..

Comment: Please show us what you have tried so far

Answer (score 55, accepted):

Some alternative solutions to an iframe are:

**AJAX** - You can use the XMLHttpRequest object to retrieve data and inject it to your page, for example inside a `div`. Example using jQuery:

```
 $( "#result" ).load( "ajax/test.html" );
```

**HTML5 Web Components** - HTML Imports, part of the Web Components, allows to bundle HTML documents in other HTML documents. That includes HTML, CSS, JavaScript or anything else an .html file can contain. Example:

```
   <link rel="import" href="http://stackoverflow.com">
```

Some other ideas are:

`<object>` tag - It defines an embedded object within an HTML document. Can be used fot HTML file and multimedia content like audio, video, applets, ActiveX, PDF and Flash or other plugins).

```
   <object data="http://stackoverflow.com" width="400" height="300" type="text/html">
        Alternative Content
    </object>
```

`<embed>` tag - It defines a container for an external application for example a plug-in, in can be also "hacked" and used to display an HTML page.

```
<embed src="http://stackoverflow.com" width=200 height=200 />
```

Regarding passing HEADER the best solution would be using an AJAX approach, here an example:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "http://stackoverflow.com",
    data: { uname: "test" },
    type: "GET",
    beforeSend: function(xhr){xhr.setRequestHeader('X-TOKEN', 'xxxxx');},
    success: function() { alert('Success!' + authHeader); }
});

or in this way,

$.ajax({
    url: "http://stackoverflow.com",
    data: { uname: "test" },
    type: "GET",
    headers:{ "X-TOKEN": 'xxxxx'},
    success: function() { alert('Success!' + authHeader); }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply.Already i tried above approach. I couldn't pass header values to that site. How can i achieve this

Comment: @PrabhuArumugam You are welcome! Consider using jQuery and $.ajax you can set there an header using beforeSend you can find a detailated documentation here http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/ Please let me know if you need further information :)

Comment: if load url http:// with domain https:// this .load function not working?

Comment: Regarding Apache configurations with default header `X-Frame-Options: "DENY"`: `<frame>`, `<iframe>`, `<embed>` or `<object>` are not rendered. See [X-Frame-Options Header](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/X-Frame-Options)

Answer (score 12):

You can try an object tag like this:

```
<object type="text/html" data="http://validator.w3.org/" width="800px" height="600px" />
```

Comment: How can I add header to this URL?

Comment: thanks ur ans was very useful. +1

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/object to help clarify the object element

Comment: How does it work for SPA websites?