# Change viewport width and height for a specific div

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, viewport, preview

I have a configurator application where you can build a website. I have an angular component which builds the website and this uses the viewport width and height for a bunch of media queries to be mobile and desktop responsive.

I want to be able to show my user a preview of what the website looks like in a mobile view.

To paint a picture, in my configurator I have a menu on the left side with basic options, a menu on top with display settings to switch between mobile view and desktop view and a menu on the right to show some more options. In the middle of the page I have my preview which contains an angular component.

Is it possible for me without using an iframe to tell this preview div that to act as if its a viewport with 400px by 800px? And then all the content inside of it will think its inside 400px by 800px?

Comment: Please include code that demonstrates the issue and allows us to reproduce it. https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: The answers to this question might help you if I understand your issue correctly: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39102215/how-to-show-external-website-inside-another-page-without-iframe

Comment: @Gabb1995 Did you able to solve it?