# How to replace child html file in parent div tag while on child html file?

Tags: javascript, php, html

I'm trying to change child HTML file to another file but it's not working

but I don't want to use an iframe.

etc.

file1.html (parent) div tag show file2.php (child)

now I want to replace file2.php  to file3.php when file2 (child) table row clicked

```
function callURL(url) {
    location.href = url;
}
```

this will load new tab.i just want to replace div tag

Comment: add your full code.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to Show External website inside another page without iFrame?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39102215/how-to-show-external-website-inside-another-page-without-iframe)

Answer (score 0):

Some alternative solutions to an iframe are:

**AJAX** - You can use the XMLHttpRequest object to retrieve data and inject it to your page, for example inside a div. Example using jQuery:

```
 $( "#result" ).load( "ajax/test.html" );
```

HTML5 Web Components - HTML Imports, part of the Web Components, allows to bundle HTML documents in other HTML documents. That includes HTML, CSS, JavaScript or anything else an .html file can contain. Example:

```
   <link rel="import" href="http://stackoverflow.com">
```

Some other ideas are:

`<object>` tag - It defines an embedded object within an HTML document. Can be used fot HTML file and multimedia content like audio, video, applets, ActiveX, PDF and Flash or other plugins).

```
   <object data="http://stackoverflow.com" width="400" height="300" type="text/html">
        Alternative Content
    </object>
```

`<embed>` tag - It defines a container for an external application for example a plug-in, in can be also "hacked" and used to display an HTML page.

```
<embed src="http://stackoverflow.com" width=200 height=200 />
```

Regarding passing HEADER the best solution would be using an AJAX approach, here an example:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "http://stackoverflow.com",
    data: { uname: "test" },
    type: "GET",
    beforeSend: function(xhr){xhr.setRequestHeader('X-TOKEN', 'xxxxx');},
    success: function() { alert('Success!' + authHeader); }
});
```

or in this way,

```
$.ajax({
    url: "http://stackoverflow.com",
    data: { uname: "test" },
    type: "GET",
    headers:{ "X-TOKEN": 'xxxxx'},
```